# How to Select Android View Tag Programmatically?

Tags: android, view, findviewbyid

```
//Need to change background color of view

final View  someView = (View)findViewById(R.id.v1);
someView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffff"));
```

### //Error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

```
//Inside main_layout.xml
<View
android:id="@+id/v1"
android:layout_width="@dimen/appbar_tabs_bottomborder"
android:layout_height="5dp"
android:background="@color/appbar_bottom_border"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: try refresh or rebuild.

Comment: have you inflated the layout file?

Comment: You need to post complete code so that we can help.

Comment: in which class do you try to call findViewById?

Answer (score 0):

You import wrong R file, you import android.R and you should import your package.R

```
com.example.exampletodo.R
```

And don't forget clean and build is sometimes a must. So better do it your self than count on automatic R creation. And you can always check your R file whether it contains your ID-s.